# Javascript Tapestry Form Submit issue

Tags: javascript

So I've been sent some HTML to upload to our website, essentially it's a login form, however the Login button does nothing when pressed in the browser. I see that it's using a "javascript:tapestry.form.submit" to submit the form using a stylized button image (img src="images/submit.png" alt="submit") which I think may be the issue.

When I change it from this button to a standard button using (input type="submit" value="Login" /) it works fine. Is there a reason anyone can think of why this button could be causing an issue not the load in the browser? The form works if you type in your details and press return.

```
<div id="loginPanel">
    <div class="text">
        <p class="loginText">Welcome</p>
        <p class="loginText">Log-in to place your order</p>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="http://coreprint.net/aspire/Login,loginForm.sdirect" id="loginForm">
        <div style="display:none;" id="loginFormhidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="formids" value="If_0,If_2,username,password,loginButton,If_4" />
            <input type="hidden" name="seedids" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="submitmode" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="submitname" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="If_0" value="F" />
            <input type="hidden" name="If_2" value="F" />
            <input type="hidden" name="If_4" value="F" />
            <input type="hidden" name="Hidden" id="Hidden" value="X" />
        </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <a href="javascript:tapestry.form.submit('loginForm', 'loginButton');" id="loginButton" class="bLink"> 
            <img src="images/submit.png" alt="submit">
        </a>
        <input type="submit" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Were you sent any javascript along with the HTML, or are there any script tags in the HTML? If not then this will be why it doesn't work.  If there are any, then post them.

Comment: ah thanks for getting back so quick Alex. No I wasn't supplied any and there's not script tags (which I think I should find in the meta tags?), I imagine I could just attach the Javascript file to the HTML in the head tags, ie <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script> etc

Comment: The most common places to find them would be between the <head> tags, or at the very bottom of the body.  If you can get the original JavaScript then great, you can use it with a script tag as per your comment.  If not then we can write something that will work equivalently.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'd imagine it should be a fairly straight forward script, as it should just be saying to use the submit on the submit.png as opposed to creating a button with the input type="submit" value="Login" syntax, or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: Doing it with javascript would be easy, as you say  On further reflection, I don't think it's the right approach however - this is purely a presentational issue rather than behavioural, so CSS would be my preferred way.  I've added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comments above, our real aim here is to change the way the submit button looks, rather than to add submit behaviour to an image.  We can do this with CSS.

```
#loginForm > input[type="submit"] {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;

  // transparent background colour
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);

  // allows the background to resize when you change width/height
  background-size:100% 100%;

  // use your submit image
  background-image: url("images/submit.png");

  // remove default button border
  border:none;

  // make a nicy pointy cursor
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

I have removed the anchor and image from the HTML, and added a blank value to the submit button so no text shows over our background image.

```
<div id="loginPanel">
    <div class="text">
        <p class="loginText">Welcome</p>
        <p class="loginText">Log-in to place your order</p>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="http://coreprint.net/aspire/Login,loginForm.sdirect" id="loginForm">
        <div style="display:none;" id="loginFormhidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="formids" value="If_0,If_2,username,password,loginButton,If_4" />
            <input type="hidden" name="seedids" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="submitmode" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="submitname" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="If_0" value="F" />
            <input type="hidden" name="If_2" value="F" />
            <input type="hidden" name="If_4" value="F" />
            <input type="hidden" name="Hidden" id="Hidden" value="X" />
        </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="" />
    </form>
</div>
```

[Working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalreturns/hq8k0ghp/)

Comment: Yes I think you're right, the Javascript is really not actually needed here and as you say rewriting that to negate that is probably the most robust solution. Thank you very much for your help, it is greatly appreciated!